# Is there a way to visualize an entire SVN repository?

Tags: svn, repository

I have an SVN repository that has multiple projects inside of it, each one of those with a tags/branches/trunk structure under them like this:

Project 1

- trunk
- tags
- branches

Project 2

- trunk
- tags
- branches

This goes on for ~40 projects.

What I would like to do is clean up any abandoned branches that may exist, however I do not know of a method to visualize the entire repository tree.  I would really like to not have to browse through each of the branches manually if I can avoid it.  Are there any stand-alone tools to accomplish this?

I realize that TortoiseSVN, Cornerstone, and similar tools do allow visually browsing the repository.  However, what I'm really looking for is a way to see the entire structure at once.  Kind of like if you could run TortoiseSVN's revision graph against the repository itself and see all the projects fully expanded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
svn ls -R [svn://|http://|file://]url/to/repository
```

Answer (score 20):

You might also look into [Gource](http://gource.io/) -- a pointlessly sexy OpenGL visualization for Subversion. It's particularly good for visualizing how a repo changes over time and how different contributors affect different pieces of the project.

Comment: Funny you should say, I actually switched us over to Mercurial awhile ago and happened to stumble upon Gource along the way.  I tried it on our SVN project and unfortunately it didn't get along too well with our weird layout so it wasn't very exciting.  Completely pointlessly sexy.  Makes good intros for development team meetings though!

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing to put some money into that tool and have a nice visual one, you can fisheye. Otherwise check sventon; it does the basics.

fisheye http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/features/repository.jsp
sventon http://sventon.org/

Comment: It might be due to misconfiguration, but with our current repo which strays quite far from the suggested SVN branching structure Fisheye completely fails to find most branches in our repo.

Comment: sventon.org has apparently been bought by a dating service.

Answer (score 4):

The Trac product (open-source) also offers a graphical view of repositories.  (among many other features)

[Trac Open Source Project](http://trac.edgewall.org/)

[Trac Source browser](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what OS you're running.

I primarily use Mac OS X, so my SVN client of choice is [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/). This app does an excellent job of visualizing the structure and comments of the repository. The GUI is very slick, intuitive, and easy to use.

If you're on Windows, I don't know much about which client is the best, but I hear most people use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

Comment: +1 for Cornerstone. It's an excellent client and makes Subversion painless.

Comment: I like both TortoiseSVN and Cornerstone, however neither of them can create a visual of the entire repository contents as far as I have been able to determine.

Answer (score 2):

I use GUI clients to to manage my SVN repositories, but another tool that I have found really useful is [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/). It's a PHP based app for viewing your repository. It has a slick interface and has syntax highlighting for your source code. You can give it the parent path of your repositories so you can see which repositories are there and quickly browse through them to see what's what. It can't actually run commands on the repositories, for obvious reasons, but once you know what you want to do you can just use the command-line.

Comment: WebSVN now redirects somewhere irrelevant.

Comment: WebSVN now is at git. Irony. https://websvnphp.github.io

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Andrew's WebSVN suggestion, I would also recommend [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/download.html).  I explain to people that WebSVN is more of a bean counter's tool while ViewVC is better suited to developers seeking more detailed information in a more efficient manner.  That's rather tongue-in-cheek, of course, but you'll see what I mean if you compare the two products.  I have deployed both in my organization.

Comment: ViewVC doesn't appear to have any real visualization, just pretty formatting of directories, commits, etc.  What I'm looking for -- as, I think, the OP is -- is a subway map like SourceTree or gitk