# Auto generate svn repo information on commit

Tags: svn

I have a small web page that has all of my svn repos on it. I am trying to find a way that I can show the directory stucture and files on the webpage with the commit messages, kind of like git or unfuddle. Is there a way I can get that info for it to be displayed on the web page? And I would prefer to have it auto update if that is possible.

Comment: What do you mean with a webpage? It points to all repo's? It provides info about them? It's a webserver (not a page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know some PHP, you can run `svn log` on the root of each svn structure. It will yield the last commit messages.

You can then use PHP to format the log into nice html pages.

Since PHP pages are generated dynamically, the log information is gathered when the page is generated (thus on the fly). If you expect a large number of users hitting the page frequently, this might not be a good solution, since this would imply a large load on the svn repos.

However some great packages already exist like WebSVN http://www.websvn.info/features/ (as you can see this package uses PHP as well).

On the other hand websites like Sourceforge, Google code, BitBucket and GitHub (in random order) already provide support to host the project and visualize it. I don't see why you should implement such things on your own.

This question is partly related to this one: [Is there a way to visualize an entire SVN repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008576/is-there-a-way-to-visualize-an-entire-svn-repository)

Comment: would that also generate the directory structure so i can click on files and show the code?

Comment: See updated answer. There are software packages implemented to visualize svn repositories like `WebSVN`: http://www.websvn.info/features/

Answer (score 0):

Just install and use ready solution - [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/)